# Sort by page information by Ascending Numbers

Tags: php, query-posts, sort, advanced-custom-fields

Basically I have a problem that I have details being pulled from advanced custom fields and I currently have them ordered by page title in ascending order.

However, instead of ordering them Ascending by Page Title, I would like to order them by my custom field: *educational_ranking*.

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=page&post_parent=2&posts_per_page=-1&orderby=&order=ASC'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo the_field('educational_ranking'); ?></td>
<td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
<td><?php echo the_field('current_students'); ?></td>
<td>£<?php echo the_field('tuition_fees'); ?></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<?php endwhile; rewind_posts(); ?>
```

Thats what I have so far, I cannot seem to work out how to sort by the field: 'educational_ranking' - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom fields wp_query

Ex

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'mytitle',
                'value' => 'title',                
                'orderby' => 'mytitle',
                'order' => 'DESC'
            ),           
        )
     );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
 if ( have_posts() ) while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo the_field('educational_ranking'); ?></td>
<td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
<td><?php echo the_field('current_students'); ?></td>
<td>£<?php echo the_field('tuition_fees'); ?></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<?php endwhile; rewind_posts(); ?>
```

Comment: I am not to sure on how to do this? How would I do this different to what I have done above?

Comment: @OwenO'Neill What is the key of your custom field(for which you want to short) ?

Comment: what do you mean by Key? The one I want is 'educational_ranking' - hope that helps!?

Comment: is there a chance that you can help?

Comment: ACF(Advanced Custom Fields) i think typically stores prefixed keys(to hide them from the WP UI), try prefixing the custom field key with `_` when you query by it, eg. `key => '_your_field'`.